# Given two linear transformations T1 and T2, show that range T1 = range T2 if and only if there is an invertible operator S such that T1=T2S.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

I am working through Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* section 3D problem 5 which states "*Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $T_1, T_2 \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Prove that range $T_1=$ range $T_2$ iff there exists an invertible operator $S\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $T_1=T_2S$*". There are other posts regarding this problem, such as the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084483/range-t-1-range-t-2-iff-there-exists-an-invertible-operator-mathcall), however my attempted solution is different from that. I am not confident mine is correct, but I am more looking so to see why that is the case so I can understand the actual solution better. Here is my attempt:

First, suppose range $T_1=$ range $T_2$. Since $V$ is finite dimensional, we can apply the fundamental theorem of linear maps and conclude range $T_1$ and range $T_2$ are finite dimensional. Because that is the case, we can define the list $w_1,w_2,...,w_m$ to be a basis of range $T_1$ and range $T_2$. By definition of range, for each vector in our basis, we have: $T_1(v_1)=w_1, T_1(v_2)=w_2...T_1(v_m)=w_m$ for $v_1,v_2,...,v_m$ AND $T_2(v'_1)=w_1,T_2(v'_2)=w_2,...,T_2(v'_m)=w_m$ for $v'_1,v'_2,...,v'_m$. By problem 4 in section 3A (I will omit the full proof for brevity), we can conclude that both $v_1,v_2,...,v_m$ and $v'_1,v'_2,...,v'_m$ are both linearly independent lists in $V$.

Extend $v_1,v_2,...,v_m$ and $v'_1,v'_2,...,v'_m$ to bases of $V$: $v_1,v_2,...,v_m,v_{m+1},...v_n$ and $v'_1,v'_2,...,v'_m,v'_{m+1},...,v'_n$. Define the linear map $S\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ as: $S(v_i)=v'_i$ for $i=1,2,...,n,n+1,...,m$. The existence and linearity of $S$ stems from the existence theorem (3.5).

Now, to show $S$ is invertible, we will show it is injective. Assume $S(v)=0$ for some $v\in V$. $S(v)=S(c_1v_1+c_2v_2,...,c_nv_n)=S(c_1v_1)+S(c_2v_2)+...+S(c_nv_n)$ $=c_1S(v_1)+c_2S(v_2)+...+c_nS(v_n)=c_1v'_1+c_2v'_2+...+c_nv'_n$, where both $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ and $v'_1,v'_2,...,v'_n$ are our bases from earlier. Thus, it follows $c_1=c_2=...=c_n=0$ by the linear independence of $v'_1,v'_2,...,v'_n$. This concludes the first part of the proof

For the second part, assume that there exists an invertible operator $S\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $T_1=T_2S$. Now, let $w=T_1(v)\in$ range $T_1$. By our assumption, $T_1(v)=T_2S(v)$. As $S(v)$ maps to some $v'\in V$, $w=T_1(v) \in$ range $T_2$. Hence, range $T_1 \subseteq$ range $T_2$.

Now, let $w=T_2(v)\in$ range $T_2$. Since $S$ is an invertible operator, it is surjective, meaning that there exists $v_s \in V$ such that $S(v_s)=v$. By our assumption, $T_1(v_s)=T_2S(v_s) \rightarrow T_1(v_s)=T_2(v)$. Thus, $w=T_2(v)\in$ range $T_1$ which implies range $T_2 \subseteq$ range $T_1$. Altogether, range $T_1$ = range $T_2$.

$\square$